# Calculating probabilities using transition matrix

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A motor insurance company grants its customers either **no discount (state 0)** or **25% discount (state 1)** or **50% discount (state 2)**. A claim-free year results in a transition to the next higher state the following year (or in the retention of the maximum discount); similarly, a year with one claim or more causes a transition to the next lower state (or the retention of the zero discount status). Under these rules, the discount status of a policyholder forms a Markov chain with state space **S = {0,1, 2}**. The transition graph for the given discount model is:

[image]

As it can be clearly seen **p and q are 0.75 and 0.25** respectively. Thus, the **transition matrix** looks like this then (this is the best way I could write the matrix here):

```
         0%     25%    50%

 0%     (0.25   0.75    0
 25%     0.25    0     0.75
 50%     0     0.25    0.75)
```

**My confusion lies in doing the following calculations using transition matrix:**

1. Subscript[P^(3), {0,2}] otherwise what it actually looks like:

[image]

(**The answer is 0.56**). But I don't understand how this was calculated. Can someone break it down for me?

2)
[image]

**The answer is 0.70** but again how was it calculated using the information I have?

3)
[image]

(**The answer is 0.063** but same confusion as before)

Comment: Please use MathJax to format your questions

Comment: I actually calculated my p and q values that way at first (0.25 and 0.75) but my prof without much explanation informed me I'm wrong and stated that p and q are 0.75 and 0.25. What I can say is that each row in a transition matrix should sum up to 1. Now if I consider the initial values I assumed for p and q (0.25 and 0.75 respectively) then that does not equal 1.

Comment: Oof yes, that is correct. I got confused and mixed this up with something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that $75$% discount rate, should be $50$% discount rate. Also the transition matrix should be $$P=\begin{bmatrix} 0.25 & 0.75 & 0\\0.25 &0 &0.75\\0 & 0.25 & 0.75\end{bmatrix}$$

Then $P_{0,2}^{(3)}$ is the entry in the first row and third column of the matrix $P^3$ (since we transitioned from state $0$ to state $2$ in $3$ steps).  Indeed we have  $$P^3=\begin{bmatrix} 0.109375 & 0.328125 & 0.5625\\0.109375 &0.1875 &0.703125\\0.0625 & 0.234375 & 0.703125\end{bmatrix}$$ and similarly one can determine the other probabilities.

On the other hand we can also use

> Chapman-Kolmogorow equations: For any $n\geq 0$, $m\geq0$, $i\in\Omega$, $j\in\Omega$ $$P_{i,j}^{n+m}=\sum_{k\in\Omega}P_{i,k}^{n}P_{k,j}^{m}.$$

See [this](https://probabilitytopics.wordpress.com/2017/09/09/chapman-kolmogorov-equations/) for an example.

Comment: I was so lost, this finally makes sense!
True that thanks, I didn't notice at first but later fixed State-2 to 50%